# How to trigger full-screen mode on play for embedded YouTube video in React Native WebView?

Tags: android, react-native, webview

I have a YouTube video embedded in a React Native WebView. I'm using the [react-native-android-fullscreen-webview-video](https://github.com/teamairship/react-native-android-fullscreen-webview-video) library for Android which works well in both portrait and landscape mode, but I need the video to default to fullscreen when the user presses play.

I've tried other libraries for this, including react-native-youtube, but each resulted in buggy playback either in portrait or landscape.

This is my code. Everything works well, I just need fullscreen play by default.

```
<WebView source={{ uri: videoUrl }} />
```

Answer (score 14):

This is working fine for me

```
<WebView
 javaScriptEnabled={true}
 scrollEnabled={false}
 allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
 userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 
 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36"
 source={{uri: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoID}?&autoplay=1&mute=1&showinfo=0&controls=1&fullscreen=1`}}
 style={styles.video}
/>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? When I try to enter fullscreen, the video stay in the top left corner and is not full width. (Portrait mode)

When I rotate my phone into landscape mode, the video disappears and everything gets reset to portrait.

Also it doesn't allow me to close full-screen mode.

Answer (score 2):

This library works

[react-native-android-fullscreen-webview-video](https://github.com/teamairship/react-native-android-fullscreen-webview-video)

```
import WebView from 'react-native-android-fullscreen-webview-video';
<WebView style={{flex:1, height: 300} source={{ uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/GV0B6nGf9mcrel=0&autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=1&fullscreen=1' }}/>
```

Comment: This ended up being the best option for me. Thank you!

Comment: This library was outdated and used  deprecated webview . Only support RN  version lower than 0.60

Answer (score 2):

I am a little late to answer this question but now you can use the react-native-youtube-iframe package to achieve this.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Modal, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import YoutubePlayer from 'react-native-youtube-iframe';
import {hp, wp} from '../../helpers/Responsiveness';

const VideoModal = ({videoId, setModal, showVideoModal}) => {
return (
<Modal
  animationType="slide"
  transparent={true}
  visible={showVideoModal}
  onRequestClose={() => {
    setModal();
  }}>
  <View style={styles.centeredView}>
    <View style={styles.modalView}>
      <YoutubePlayer
        height={hp(100)}
        width={wp(100)}
        play={false}
        videoId={videoId}
        webViewProps={{
          injectedJavaScript: `
        var element = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
        element.style.position = 'unset';
        element.style.paddingBottom = 'unset';
        true;
      `,
        }}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
</Modal>
 );
 };

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
centeredView: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
},
modalView: {
backgroundColor: 'black',
alignItems: 'center',
shadowColor: '#000',
shadowOffset: {
  width: 0,
  height: 2,
  },
shadowOpacity: 0.25,
shadowRadius: 4,
elevation: 5,
height: '100%',
width: '100%',
justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  modalText: {
  marginBottom: 15,
  textAlign: 'center',
  },
  });

export default VideoModal;
```

Comment: how can we show user-readable error if we face an issue on the network

Comment: Where is import {hp, wp} from '../../helpers/Responsiveness';

Comment: @RohitParte that is the custom height & width that I use for responsiveness, you can give height & width as you like

Comment: @MuhammadHaidar Have you got any way for dynamic HW?

Answer (score 1):

try this way and you can use many iframe property for youtube button and many things to do

```
<WebView
        style={{flex:1}}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZZ5LpwO-An4?rel=0&autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&fullscreen=1'}}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Can you elaborate on how I might use iFrame properties to open to fullscreen when the user presses play?

Comment: Here's the official documentation of iframe properties https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters but i will suggest you tu use react-native-youtube for that that so easy to implement...

Comment: Thank you. I tried react-native-youtube but it was very buggy. Always autoplayed and the video didn't work correctly in portrait mode (because of a documented issue).

Comment: I read the documents thoroughly. This is what I'm referring to: https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube#known-issues

Comment: Which bugs and error are you facing tell me i have mamy example for this..

Comment: when using full-screen mode the video opens to landscape on Android as expected. But if the user returns the screen to portrait mode, the video plays in 1 second increments before pausing. We think something is blocking the view but can't determine what. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code:

```
allowFullScreen: {true}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```js
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

 
 <WebView
   originWhitelist={["*"]}
   showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
   showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
   automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
   style={[styles.youtubeWebview]}
   nestedScrollEnabled={false}
   allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
   javaScriptEnabled={true}
   scrollEnabled={false}
   source={{
    uri: videoUrl,
     }}
    />
```

**allowsFullscreenVideo={true}**